# Mostrar modal mientras se descarga archivo

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un botón cuya función es descargar un archivo, sin embargo este proceso a veces es muy largo y lo ideal es mostrar un mensaje de "cargando" mientras se genera el archivo, pero al usar `ajax = "false` no puedo usar las funciones onStar`PrimeFaces.monitorDownload` pero no me funciona:

xhtml:

```
 <p:commandLink id="btnExportar" class="boton"
                                   value="Exportar a Excel"
                                   action="#{consultaCtrl.exportar}"
                                   onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus(), hideStatus())"
                                   ajax="false"/>
                    <p:tooltip id="toolTipExportar" for="btnExportar" value="Exporta filas visibles a Excel"   position="left"/>

  <p:dialog widgetVar="cargando" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false" styleClass="small centered-all">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </p:dialog> 

<script>
        function showStatus() {
            PF('statusDialog').show();
        }

        function hideStatus() {
            PF('statusDialog').hide();
        }
    </script>
```

Controlador:

```
public void exportar() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    String name = periodo.getLabel() + ".xls";
    ec.responseReset();
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"");

    try (OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream()) {
        exportarExcelService.exportar((List<Guia>) guias.getAllPagesGuias(), periodo.getLinea(), output);
        try (CountingOutputStream co = new CountingOutputStream(output)) {
            System.out.println("termine");
            ec.setResponseContentLength((int) co.getByteCount());
            co.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al obtener el tamaño del stream " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al intentar crear el excel " + e.getMessage());
    }

    fc.responseComplete();

}
```

Comment: Pregunta, porque no pasas el  tu stream al componente download de prime faces y ahí metes un ajax status ?

Comment: no sé cómo hacer eso, ¿Podrias explicarme más?

Comment: Encontré un ejemplo aquí : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml pero no sé como adaptarlo a mi implementación.

Comment: ¿que versión de Primefaces usas Gibran?

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema pero lo solucione de la siguiente manera también te sirve para usarlo dentro de un dialog.

```
<h:commandButton id="btnExportar" 
                 actionListener="#{consultaCtrl.exportar}" 
                 value="Exportar a Excel" 
                 class="estilo_botones"
                 onclick="PF('statusDialog').show();"
                 onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();">

      <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@form"/>

</h:commandButton>
<p:tooltip id="toolTipExportar" for="btnExportar" value="Exporta filas visibles a Excel"   position="left"/>


<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Procesando" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco tu código?

Comment: ¿el dialogo se quita al completar la exportación?